# Title And Limits Repeating with Hold Off

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to show how a fitted function differs for different time ranges within a function, but the graph title keeps repeating and the fit curve ends at the limits of the previous graph -- is my code wrong or is this a bug? I've tried creating the same fit twice but this hasn't helped. thanks! (r2023b)
[code and graphs in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1n7t.png)

Comment: Please don’t post pictures of code, it’s hard to read (for some impossible to read) and we can’t run or modify the code. See here for more reasons: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/7328782

Answer (score 1):

Worked out my answer -- normal plot notation doesn't work for plotting fits -- create a new figure for each graph with

```
figure
```

and use

```
hold off
```

After the first plot for each
-- this separates the graphs and the limits properly :-)